# Define dynamic separator for Properties.load in java

Tags: java, properties

I know that properties in the string can be loaded to a java.util.Properties when it is separated by \n as follows.

Is there any way to do the providing a separator dynamically eg : can we use a comma (,) as a separator?

```
String  propertiesString = "#Namal=153\nJanith=253\nSameera=135";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesString));
```

Comment: Unhandled exception type IOException Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tokenize the commas and join them using newlines before loading it into java.util.Properties.

Sample code below uses [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and assumes you're on UNIX newlines (\n)

```
String propStr = "Monday=1,Tuesday=2,Wednesday=3";
String[] propsArray = StringUtils.split(propStr, ',');
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new StringReader(StringUtils.join(propsArray, "\n")));
```

Comment: Or you can just `propStr = propStr.replace(",", "\n")` so you don't have to `split` and then `join` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No,you can't do this!And it's not worthy,just do it with a String .
The '\n' is default line separator, and there is a LineReader inner class which define the logic of line-reading operation,I don't think you have a chance to interact with it.

Comment: +1 for saying there is a LineReader inner class which define the logic of line-reading operation

Comment: I think it is not worthy if the properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesString)); is dedicated only for dealing with files. but since it can be used with the String as well. I think it is worthy to have a possibility of adding dynamic separators as well.

Answer (score 0):

Properties class is an utility designed to load configurations.

Since \n is the newline character, I can only assume that it was chosen to make the property files easily readable.

If your requirement is to get some data stored in a custom format you can always read them and manually parse the configs using `Scanner`

Or go with a XML config file with a good schema.

BTW what's wrong with using the new line as a separator? I can only assume that you want to use Properties file to load a different kind of a file because for me the format of the property class make perfect sense in terms of usability and readability.

Comment: yes I agree that this can be done through tokenising and looping. But I was tried for a one lined solution like properties.load(new StringReader(stringToLoad)).

Comment: New line is perfectly OK. I think only it is enough if the properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesString)); is dedicated only for dealing with files. but since it can be used with the String as well, I think it is worthy to have a possibility of adding dynamic separators as well.

Comment: One line solution don't exist, at least not as far as I know, unless you create your own class.